# How to visual a colored mesh from a OBJ file only with vertex color (without MLT file) in PCL?

Tags: point-cloud-library, pcl

I want to visual a OBJ file with color in PCL visualizer.

PCL provides `pcl::io::loadPolygonFileOBJ()` and `pcl::io::loadOBJFile()` to load data to `pcl::TextureMesh`.

But these two functions require that the OBJ file is accompanied by an MIT file. The OBJ file I have has the following format (I uploaded one of the files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iG6OwFnyzdHRT8asWpOxkvmV9SkXNXtc/view?usp=sharing))

```
v -2.160000 -0.241949 0.210000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v -2.170000 -0.240332 0.210000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
v -2.160000 -0.241100 0.220000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
...
f 3 2 1
...
```

How can I read my OBJ files in PCL and visualize it with color?

---

Comment: `pcl::io::loadOBJFile()` does not require an MTL file

Comment: `pcl::TextureMesh` has an attribute named `tex_materials`. Without MLT files, how can OBJ files save Materials? Except for my own OBJ files, OBJ files with texture I downloaded from the Internet all have MTL files, so I can't try to use `pcl::io::loadOBJFile()` to normally read an OBJ file without MTL files but has texture information